# Converting Website to WebApplication. BlogEngine.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, blogengine.net

So I am trying to convert the Latest repository from BlogEngine. They are using MVC3. Now I moved all the files, Renamed App_Code-->Set to Compile. Converted all the Files to Web Application. My only problem is I keep getting: 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Helpers' does not exist in the current context

```
<div>@Helpers.ExtensionsHelper.GetExtensions(true)</div>
```

Comment: This is just a guess: Check if you are missing any assemblies related to Razor e.g. System.Web.WebPages / System.Web.Helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlogEngine.NET doesn't really use MVC, but it uses Razor web pages that usually installed with MVC 3 or Webmatrix. If you don't have those installed, you need to move DLLs from downloaded lib/Razor folder into application's /bin folder.